# Filter List of Items for Returns in a Date Range

Tags: sql

I am writing a proc to order products and I am quite lost as to how to get the desired results. The SQL will include an item number and a date in which the item was sold. We want to get a list of items that have sold more than three items in a date range without a gap of 6 months to put on a list to order. I am completely lost as to how to proceed.

I have got a list of items and attempted and have tried to create tables based on the 3 hits in a year without a 6 month gap in sales but I cannot get it to filter properly.

```
SELECT   S.Product
        ,S.SaleDate
FROM     PSales S
WHERE    S.SaleDate BETWEEN '2018-08-08' AND '2019-08-08'
```

This will give my list of items which I am putting into a table, I need to use this table to filter for the results I am looking for.

Comment: Why are you putting that into a table? You can simply use the result of that as the input for an `IN` condition.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something in the lines of:

```
SELECT S.Product ,S.SaleDate, Count(*)
    FROM PSales S
    WHERE S.SaleDate BETWEEN '2018-08-08' AND '2019-08-08' 
    GROUP BY S.Product 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```